# uuid missing when running ./configure for cryptsetup-1.7.3 install

Tags: encryption, uuid

So, one week into my first ever Linux computer and out of all the rookie issues I'm having, this one is the most pressing.

While running the ./configure command for the cryptsetup-1.7.3 file I've extracted to my desktop, everything comes back fine except for uuid:
checking uuid/uuid.h usability... no
checking uuid/uuid.h presence... no
checking for uuid/uuid.h... no
configure: error: You need the uuid library.

I used sudo apt to install the library, and if I run the command to generate a key (I've forgotten the exact command) using uuid it works, so it must be present in some capacity.

If anyone has some advice it would be greatly appreciated, having the ability to encrypt my external HDD is pretty vital before I can start my therapy work.

Thank you

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using, and why are you trying to install cryptsetup from source (rather than using the prebuilt version from the repository)?

Comment: 16.04, and I just downloaded the files from the site, extracted them, and followed the instructions in the files (or attempted to). Is there any easier way?

Answer (score 1):

I got past this, and subsequent dependency issues, by installing the following packages (with their dependencies):

1. uuid-dev
2. libdevmapper-dev
3. libpopt-dev
4. libgcrypt20-dev